# this.handleClick vs this.handleClick()

Tags: reactjs

I have two examples. In first example I have used this.handleClick() inside JSX and it does not work. However, In 2nd exampel I have used this.handleClick inside JSX and it works. I think, I am missing some basics.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);

this.state = {counter: 0};
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
} 

handleClick() {
this.setState({counter: this.state.counter + this.props.increment});
}


render() {
return(
  <div>
    <p> Current counter is {this.state.counter} </p>
    <button onClick={this.handleClick()} > Click here </button>
  </div>
  );
  }
  }


  function App() {
  return (
  <div>
      <MyComponent increment={5} />
  </div>
 );
 }
```

Comment: correct way is to use `this.handleClick`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`this.handleClick()` this will call the method and return it's return value while `this.handleClick` it just the method reference

in your code

```
<button onClick={this.handleClick()} > Click here </button>
```

you making `onClick` equals to what `this.handleClick()` returns which is nothing while this

```
<button onClick={this.handleClick} > Click here </button>
```

will make onClick refer to `this.handleClick` method

---

checkout this example

```js
function foo(){
    return 5;
}

console.log(foo());
console.log(foo);
```

logging `foo()` will be equals to 5 but logging `foo` will equals to function it self